# Change / override log event level in Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

Is there a way to change the log level of certain events dynamically? (maybe by namespace or a predicate)

I'm looking for something like `.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)` but what I really want to do is change the level of `Information` events coming from the `Microsoft` namespace to `Verbose`. Events of higher importance should be left as-is.

EDIT:

Enrichers can't change the log event level. 
[image]

Comment: Yes, Serilog documentation shows you exactly how to dynamically change the level. Look at Enrichers to further customize.

Comment: @Crowcoder Nope, sadly they can't - see update in post.

Comment: I'm either misunderstanding or you didn't come across this: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events#dynamic-levels

Comment: This is different. This changes the lower limit of *all* the collected events. (so I change e.g. information to warning during runtime so anything below warning will be thrown away)

What I want is to downgrade certain events from certain sources to verbose from information. I want information level events logged from most sources, just not from all of them.

Comment: I think you may need to create multiple logger configurations for that but hopefully someone else knows for sure.

Comment: Question: are you using Serilog's `ILogger` or Microsoft's `ILogger<T>` when actually logging the events? (and yes, I realize this is somewhat old... but your answer is relevant in potential ways to do this).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's possible, but not entirely straightforward, so strap yourself in!

#### 1. Create a sink wrapper

Instead of an enricher, you'll need to create a wrapper around the target sink. The wrapper will receive events from the logging pipeline, (fairly cheaply) create new events with identical properties, and forward them to the actual sink:

```
class LevelBoostingWrapper : ILogEventSink, IDisposable
{
    readonly ILogEventSink _wrappedSink;

    public LevelBoostingWrapper(ILogEventSink wrappedSink)
    {
        _wrappedSink = wrappedSink;
    }

    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        if (logEvent.Level == LogEventLevel.Warning)
        {
            var boosted = new LogEvent(
                logEvent.Timestamp,
                LogEventLevel.Error, // <- the boost
                logEvent.Exception,
                logEvent.MessageTemplate,
                logEvent.Properties
                    .Select(kvp => new LogEventProperty(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)));

            _wrappedSink.Emit(boosted);
        }
        else
        {
            _wrappedSink.Emit(logEvent);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        (_wrappedSink as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The actual criterion for deciding which events to modify is up to you, of course.

#### 2. Hook the wrapper into the configuration syntax

This little extension makes it more pleasant to set up the wrapper:

```
static class LoggerSinkConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration Boosted(
        this LoggerSinkConfiguration lsc,
        Action<LoggerSinkConfiguration> writeTo)
    {
        return LoggerSinkConfiguration.Wrap(
            lsc,
            wrapped => new LevelBoostingWrapper(wrapped),
            writeTo);
    }
}
```

#### 3. Add the wrapper to the configuration

Finally, in the logger configuration, apply the wrapper:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Boosted(wt => wt.Console())
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Information("This will be unchanged");
Log.Warning("This will be boosted to Error");
       
Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

Comment: Beside the Filters, and Enrichers, the serilog could allow us to add a Transform as well. Nice feature huh ?

Comment: Nicholas, what if you want to wrap a sink that is actually configured in appsettings.config/web.config?

Comment: nice one, but if I have both wrapper AND enricher, can I configure the enricher to act AFTER the wrapper?

Comment: I posted below my full solution to mix wrapper/sink and enricher, using the subLogger.

Comment: In your example where you have `// <- the boost` shouldn't it be `LogEventLevel.Error`? Seems like otherwise you're just boosting from Warning to Warning. Or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: Also, in the nearly 3 years since you wrote this answer, has anything changed that might streamline this process more? Entity Framework Core, Hangfire, and ASP.NET Core are all very noisy loggers, they log quite a few events at an Information level that we'd like to force down to Debug or Verbose, while still retaining Warning and above as they are.

Comment: Thanks @mason - fixed! Nothing new in this area, but not off the table for a future version :-)

Answer (score 3):

This solution is just a more concrete example based on Nicholas answer above.

In my .NET Core 3.1 application, I got the same requirement as Tamas to change the log level. I had also the requirement to create Audit logs.

More specifically, I want to keep the default http client logging defined in https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/Logging/LoggingHttpMessageHandler.cs
but have it as DEBUG instead of INFO.

I tried the Serilog UseSerilogRequestLogging as defined in 
https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/
https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-mvc-logging/
but without success.

I already created an Enricher which get the log level and create another property from it. I could extend this enricher to report a lower level as the real log level for httpClient, but it does not solve the logging, just display it differently.

The sink defined by Nicholas above is the correct approach.

The tricky part is to get the enricher AFTER the sink.
So for that, we can create a sub logger as documented in the bottom part of https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics

Some code to show a concrete example

```
public sealed class HttpClientLogLevelWrapper : ILogEventSink, IDisposable
{
    private const string SourceContext = "SourceContext";
    private const string HttpClientNamespace = "\"System.Net.Http.HttpClient";

    private readonly ILogEventSink _wrappedSink;
    private readonly LogEventLevel _logEventLevelTarget;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="HttpClientLogLevelWrapper"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wrappedSink">The wrapped sink.</param>
    /// <param name="logEventLevelTarget">The log event level target.</param>
    public HttpClientLogLevelWrapper(ILogEventSink wrappedSink, LogEventLevel logEventLevelTarget)
    {
        _wrappedSink = wrappedSink;
        _logEventLevelTarget = logEventLevelTarget;
    }

    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        if (logEvent == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logEvent));
        }

        if (IsHttpClientInfoLog(logEvent))
        {
            var newLogEvent = new LogEvent(logEvent.Timestamp,
                _logEventLevelTarget,  // this is the only differnce with the original logEvent
                logEvent.Exception, logEvent.MessageTemplate,
                logEvent.Properties.Select(kvp => new LogEventProperty(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)));
            _wrappedSink.Emit(newLogEvent);
        }
        else
        {
            _wrappedSink.Emit(logEvent);
        }
    }

    private static bool IsHttpClientInfoLog(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        if (logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue(SourceContext, out LogEventPropertyValue sourceContext))
        {
            string className = sourceContext.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(className)
                && className.StartsWith(HttpClientNamespace, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                && logEvent.Level == LogEventLevel.Information)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        (_wrappedSink as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }
}

public static class LoggerSinkConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration LowerHttpClientLoggingSink(this LoggerSinkConfiguration lsc, Action<LoggerSinkConfiguration> writeTo)
    {
        return LoggerSinkConfiguration.Wrap(lsc, wrapped => new HttpClientLogLevelWrapper(wrapped, LogEventLevel.Verbose), writeTo, LogEventLevel.Debug, null);
    }
}
```

and then the now quite complex configuration of the Logger in Program/Main

```
 // First read the wished minimum logger level, read from the enviromment variable.
 LogEventLevel minimumLoggerLevel = GetMinimumLogLevelFromEnvironmentVariable();

 // global shared logger, created BEFORE the host build to be able to log starting and ending the service.
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
     .MinimumLevel.Is(minimumLoggerLevel) 
     .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
     .Enrich.FromLogContext()
     .Enrich.WithThreadId()
     .WriteTo.LowerHttpClientLoggingSink(wt => wt  // LowerHttpClientLogging update the log level from Info to Debug for HttpClient related logs.
        .Logger(lc => lc  // require a sub logger to have the Enrich AFTER the Sink!
        .Enrich.With(new LogLevelEnricher(LoggerAudit.AuditProperty, LogLevelUpperName)) // create levelUpper property and manage AuditProperty AFTER the sink!             
         .WriteTo
         .Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff} [{ThreadId}] {" + LogLevelUpperName + "} - {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")))
         .CreateLogger();
```

The outputTemplate above is actually meant to match the pattern defined for log4j in other projects, since this pattern is then considered by filebeat for ElasticSearch/Kibana.

Answer (score 1):

This sink wrapping is great for default sinks. However I would like to configure serilog using a config file, but also wrap the configured sinks to modify specific calls to a lower loglevel.

This is the configuration of my sinks in appsetting.json

```
{
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Verbose",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "System": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "Console",
            "Args": {
                "outputTemplate": "===> {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "RollingFile",
            "Args": {
                "pathFormat": "c:\path\file.txt",
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] - {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "DurableHttpUsingTimeRolledBuffers",
            "Args": {
                "requestUri": "https://[elastic]",
                "bufferPathFormat": "c:\path\file.json"
            }
        }
```

Now what I do is create a logger from this config:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                  .Build();
var configLoggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration);
var configLogger = configLoggerConfig.CreateLogger();
```

And then try to wrap it:

```
var wrappedLoggerconfig = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.LogLevelModifyingSink(wt => wt.Sink(configLogger), modifiers, levelSwitch);
        Log.Logger = wrappedLoggerconfig.CreateLogger();
```

The modifiers is a class that contains the logic for a specific event to be modified.
The LogModifyingSink extentionmethod looks lik this:

```
public static LoggerConfiguration LogLevelModifyingSink(
         this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,
         Action<LoggerSinkConfiguration> writeTo,
         ILogLevelModifiers logLevelModifiers,
         LoggingLevelSwitch levelSwitch)
    {
        return LoggerSinkConfiguration.Wrap(
            loggerConfiguration,
            wrapped => new LogLevelModifyingSink(wrapped, logLevelModifiers),
            writeTo,
            LogEventLevel.Verbose,
            levelSwitch); 
    }
```

In which the LogLevelModifyingSink is the wrappersink that emits the modified log:

```
public class LogLevelModifyingSink : ILogEventSink, IDisposable
{
    readonly ILogEventSink wrappedSink;
    readonly IEnumerable<LogLevelModifier> logLevelModifiers;

    public LogLevelModifyingSink(ILogEventSink wrappedSink, ILogLevelModifiers logLevelModifiers)
    {
        this.wrappedSink = wrappedSink;
        this.logLevelModifiers = logLevelModifiers?.GetLevelModifiers();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        (wrappedSink as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }

    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        var message = logEvent.RenderMessage();
        Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString() + " " + message);

        if (wrappedSink != null && logLevelModifiers != null && logLevelModifiers.Any())
        {
            foreach(var modifier in logLevelModifiers)
            {
                if (modifier.ShouldModify(logEvent))
                {
                    wrappedSink.Emit(modifier.ModifyEvent(logEvent));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        wrappedSink.Emit(logEvent);
    }
}
```

Now this works partly. The logmessages are handled by the wrapper for all 3 sinks, however, by creating a logger from a new configuration, the settings for minumumlevel and minimumlevel overrides are not conveyed from the config file and there seams no way to get these settings at runtime.
I feel like this solution is not the way to go since I create a logger twice. So my question is, is there a better way to wrap sinks from configuration? Is it possible at all? And how can I preserve my configured settings?

Comment: @Nicholas Blumhardt I opened a ticket on github based on this answer and your comments https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1491

Comment: this works fairly well but you need to filter out the `WriteTo`s' from the configuration (before loading it the second time into the wrapped logger) to avoid duplicate logging. However doing that will make the static logging methods such as  `Serilog.Log.Information` or `Serilog.Log.Logger.Information` stop working (looks like those static methods require a direct `WriteTo` and not any `WriteTo` to a wrapped sink.