# How can I change message template in LogEvent?

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I use scopes and structured logs extensively in my code bases. All the logs are then sent to Logstash and can be viewed in Kibana. But I have a problem with Logstash indexes such as that a property with a name must have the same type of value throughout all the logs. As a mitigation I came up with an idea to add suffixes to all my structured logs and scopes, but it's very tiresome and I could easily forget about adding suffixes manually, so I tried to write a custom enricher to add suffixes to property names.

Basically, I want to automatically transform this:

```cs
logger.LogInformation("Some log message with a {NamedProperty}", 42);
```

to this

```cs
logger.LogInformation("Some log message with a {NamedProperty.MyCustomSuffix}", 42);
```

This enricher searches for all named properties in a log and changes their names in properties dictionary. But I can't find a way to also change the template since it is apparently immutable.

```cs
public class NamedPropertiesTransformer : ILogEventEnricher
{
    readonly string _suffix;

    public NamedPropertiesTransformer(string suffix) => _suffix = suffix;

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        var propertyTokenNames = logEvent.MessageTemplate.Tokens
            .Where(_ => _ is PropertyToken {IsPositional: false})
            .Cast<PropertyToken>()
            .Select(_ => _.PropertyName)
            .ToHashSet();

        var properties = logEvent.Properties.Where(_ => propertyTokenNames.Contains(_.Key));

        foreach (var (name, value) in properties)
        {
            logEvent.RemovePropertyIfPresent(name);
            logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(new($"{name}.{_suffix}", value));
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to somehow achieve that?

Comment: If the *value* types must be the same, why modify the template?  You should be converting the event value to the one expected by the parameter. Even better, refactor the code and put all logging calls in a single class. This way, if you want to modify the template you'll only have to modify a single method instead of searching all instances where the template is used

Comment: We use a single index for each team so we can't know what type every property across all the teams must have. Regarding your second suggestion, I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: If you don't know what type a property needs, how are you going to fix the template? Create eg a `LogEvents` static class with event-specific logging methods, and make the log call there, eg `OrderCreated(this ILogger logger, int orderId)=>logger.LogInformation("bla bla {OrderID}",orderId);`. That's similar to the DemoEventSource [in the EventSource docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/eventsource-getting-started)

Comment: Log events are an artifact too. By putting them in a single file you make your own code cleaner and can modify the log event itself without affecting the rest of the code. It's also a lot easier to edit templates this way. By using a method with strongly typed parameters you avoid passing the wrong type or mixing up values.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource is completely different .net subsystem compared to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging that OP had used. If you think that both can be used in conjunction you should give better clarification with reasoning and examples.

Comment: @Feofilakt not Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Serilog. You mixed up different libraries, not just subsystems. And I said similar, not same. As in "look at this similar solution". I think I should return your unfortunate comment. Next time read instead of trying to find reasons to attack

Comment: @Feofilakt besides, in 2024 the discussion would be around [SerilogTracing](https://nblumhardt.com/2024/03/from-serilog-timings-to-tracing/) and how Elastic, OpenSearch, Logstash etc can receive OpenTelemetry traces directly without any need for text formatting. And how using span tags is infinitely better than trying to determine the recipient of events by parsing. And even then, it's better to concentrate the log templates methods to a single class than have them spread around with possible tiny differences

Comment: @Feofilakt had you actually read the article you'd notice that what it proposes is similar to Microsoft.Extension.Logging's [compile-time source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logger-message-generator).

Comment: Sorry if my comment has seemed harsh, thats probably cause I'm not speak english good enough to distinguish emotional tonality. Regarding the topic: as I understand now, you were not suggesting to use EventSource, but to take it as an example for creating helper methods, right? I'm facing the same problem now (need to truncate long messages / message templates). Probably will use solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47046128/2763447.